# MySQL - Get LAST_INSERT_ID() of a Mass-Insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to insert a number of rows(~100,000) into a table.
The table has one column "Id" that is auto-incremented.

LAST_INSERT_ID(); returns the last auto-incremented id of the connection session, but is there **any way of getting the LAST_INSERT_ID() of a mass insert?**

For Example:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (null, somedata),(null, somedata),(null, somedata),...
```

**I know it isn't directly possible in MySQL, but is there any work-around?**

Comment: Why not last_insert_id?

Comment: It is returning the last inserted id, but only one id, when you are doing a mass insert as shown, you are getting only one of the ids